# Использую Select2 для поиска данных по файлу JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select2

Использую плагин [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) для поиска данных по файлу JSON возвращаемого через PHP. Проблема в том что не ищутся и не сортируются совпадающие теги. Тупо выводит все значения при вводе что-то в input. помогите разобраться в настройках)

```
$(".search select").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/index.php/search/jsonTags?type=1",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                query: params.term,
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            var items =  $.map(data, function(item, i, params) {
                    return {
                        text: '#' + item.tag,
                        slug: item.tag,
                        id: item.tag
                    };
                });

            return {results: items};
        }
    },
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    placeholder: "Введите хеш тег",
    language: "ru",
    templateResult: function (data) {
        if (data.id === '') { // adjust for custom placeholder values
            return 'Custom styled placeholder text';
        }

        var term = $('.select2-search__field').val();
        var $text = $('<span>'+data.text.replace(term, '<strong>'+term+'</strong>')+'</span>');
        return $text;
    }
});
```

а данные в JSON вот такие:

```
[
  {
    "tag": "циркон"
  },
  {
    "tag": "серьги"
  },
  {
    "tag": "кольцо"
  },
  {
    "tag": "крест"
  },
  {
    "tag": "обр.кольцо"
  },
  {
    "tag": "пирсингвнос"
  },
  {
    "tag": "колье"
  },
  {
    "tag": "подвес"
  },
  {
    "tag": "пирсинг"
  },
  {
    "tag": "кольцопомолвочное"
  },
  {
    "tag": "икона"
  },
  {
    "tag": "серьга-кафф"
  },
  {
    "tag": "браслет"
  },
  {
    "tag": "печатка"
  },
  {
    "tag": "серьги-пусеты"
  },
  {
    "tag": "пирсинг_в_нос"
  },
  {
    "tag": "звезда"
  },
  {
    "tag": "серьги-продевки"
  },
  {
    "tag": "брошь"
  },
  {
    "tag": "сувенир"
  },
  {
    "tag": "слейв-браслет"
  },
  {
    "tag": "шнурок"
  },
  {
    "tag": "медальон"
  },
  {
    "tag": "подвески_на_с/з"
  },
  {
    "tag": "значок"
  },
  {
    "tag": "ложка_детская"
  },
  {
    "tag": "серьги_детские"
  },
  {
    "tag": "запонки"
  },
  {
    "tag": "зажим"
  },
  {
    "tag": "шарм"
  },
  {
    "tag": "цепь"
  },
  {
    "tag": "серьги-конго"
  },
  {
    "tag": "кольцо_помолвочное"
  },
  {
    "tag": "комплект"
  },
  {
    "tag": "погремушка"
  },
  {
    "tag": "мощевик"
  },
  {
    "tag": "четки"
  },
  {
    "tag": "наперст_молитва"
  },
  {
    "tag": "ложка_чайная"
  },
  {
    "tag": "вилка_десертная"
  },
  {
    "tag": "ложка_десертная"
  },
  {
    "tag": "ситечко"
  },
  {
    "tag": "ложка_кофейная"
  },
  {
    "tag": "рюмка"
  },
  {
    "tag": "бр.для_очищ.воды"
  },
  {
    "tag": "зажим_для_денег"
  },
  {
    "tag": "брелок"
  },
  {
    "tag": "брошь-кулон"
  },
  {
    "tag": "чашка_кофейная"
  },
  {
    "tag": "чашка"
  },
  {
    "tag": "накл.на_пуговицы"
  },
  {
    "tag": "серьга-пусета"
  },
  {
    "tag": "часы_мужские"
  }
]
```

Их очень много) Зачем минусовать то?) помогли бы лучше разобраться с плагином....

Comment: использую данный плагин в [tag:asp.net-mvc], у Вас этот метод `/index.php/search/jsonTags?type=1`, принимает параметр `query`?

Comment: Принимает параметр `type` с 0 до 4. [например](http://test2.jewfoto.ru/search/jsonTags?type=0)

Comment: этот Ваш метод должен дополнительно принимать строку(это то что будет введено пользователем в соответствующее поле), и на основании данной строки возвращать *фильтрованный* список тагов, т.е. пользователь ввел, сервер обработал исходный список, и вернул те стоки которые удовлетворяют условию

Comment: Можете пример показать?

Comment: пример чего? `php` кода который будет *фильтровать* исходный список? если да то к сожалению нет. я пишу на [tag:c#]

Comment: т.е. в данной ситуации php должен фильтровать и отправить уже фильтрованный JSON?

Comment: да именно, т.е. клиент вводит текст в поле, а сервер на основании этого ввода отдает список тагов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основании уточняющих комментариев к исходному вопросу у Вас проблема что Вы возвращаете не фильтрованный список *тагов*.

Что бы в выпадающем списке отображались *таги* соответствующие условию введенному пользователем необходимо

1. Модифицировать метод `/index.php/search/jsonTags` на сервере который возвращает список *тагов*: добавить параметр `query` тип `string` в котором будет содержаться пользовательский ввод;
2. В теле метода `jsonTags` осуществить фильтрацию исходных данных: например `select * from tags where tag like {здесь условия проверки}`;
3. Полученный массив *тагов* преобразовываем в `json` и отдать на клиента.

Answer (score 0):

Значит предварительно обработайте массив объектов - удалить дубликаты, по примеру этого [решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript).

```js
var thing = [{
  "tag": "циркон"
}, {
  "tag": "серьги"
}, {
  "tag": "циркон"
}, {
  "tag": "крест"
}, {
  "tag": "крест"
}, {
  "tag": "крест"
}];

var arr = {};

for (var i = 0, len = thing.length; i < len; i++)
  arr[thing[i]['tag']] = thing[i];

thing = new Array();
for (var key in arr)
  thing.push(arr[key]);


console.log(thing);
document.getElementById('divT').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(thing);
```

```html
<div id="divT"></div>
```

Comment: Так там дубликатов нет) я их через PHP фильтрую а потом уже передаю в JSON

Comment: @pwnz22 тогда что за совпадающие теги?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/dbdd35da9ffbd2d6900dc2a3bc830d34.png - вот ввожу первые буквы название тегов ответы должны отфильтроваться и жирным выделятся( но походу я что-то в JS нето сделал(

Comment: @pwnz22 ну так уберите символ решетки и будут фильтроваться и выделяться.

Comment: странно, но когда я убираю решетку при вводе результаты вообще не выдает( появляется ошибка `Cannot read property 'replace' of null` в консоле