# Проблемка с плагином Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

В предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522918/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E-select2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83-json) у меня была проблемка с фильтрацией. С этим разобрались. Теперь у меня другая проблема, никак немогу исправить, все испробывал. В одной станичке делаю 5 селектов с помощью Select2. Проблема в том что первый селект работает как надо. Фильтрует слова и в списке выводит их жирным. А вот в остальных так не получается, тоесть жирным не выделяется написанное слово в селекте
Код:

[image: Это первый селект]
[image: Это второй селект]

```
// article

    $(".search_article select").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "/index.php/search/jsonTags?type=0",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    query: params.term,
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function(data, params) {
                var items =  $.map(data, function(item, i, params) {
                        return {
                            text: item.tag,
                            slug: item.tag,
                            id: item.tag
                        };
                    });

                return {results: items};
            }
        },
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        placeholder: "Введите ариткул",
        language: "ru",
        templateResult: function (data) {
            if (data.id === '') { // adjust for custom placeholder values
                return 'Custom styled placeholder text';
            }

            var term = $('.select2-search__field').val();
            var $text = $('<span>'+data.text.replace(term, '<strong>'+term+'</strong>')+'</span>');
            return $text;
        }
    });




// material

   $(".material select").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "/index.php/search/jsonTags?type=2",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    query: params.term,
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function(data, params) {
                var items =  $.map(data, function(item, i, params) {
                        return {
                            text: item.tag,
                            slug: item.tag,
                            id: item.tag
                        };
                    });

                return {results: items};
            }
        },
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        placeholder: "Введите материал",
        language: "ru",
        templateResult: function (data) {
            if (data.tag === '') { // adjust for custom placeholder values
                return 'Custom styled placeholder text';
            }

            var term = $('.select2-search__field').val();
            var $text = $('<span>'+data.text.replace(term, '<strong>'+term+'</strong>')+'</span>');
            return $text;
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="search_article">
    <span>Артикул</span>
    <select name="article" id="article" multiple="multiple"></select>
 </div>

  <div class="material">
    <span>Материал</span>
    <select name="material" id="material" multiple="multiple"></select>
  </div>
```

`$('<span>'+data.text.replace(term, '<strong>'+term+'</strong>')+'</span>');`

вот это строчка отвечает за это) но почему оно второй раз не работает немогу понять. функция data.text.replace(,)

Comment: Открой исходник плагина и смотри как он рендерит результаты, увидишь чего не хватает или в чём проблема. В своём проекте полностью переопределял этот метод, т.к. стандартный рендер полностью не подходил, всё там удобно и понятно.

Comment: Я сейчас попробую посмотреть, но с JS у меня не все ок) просто дело в том что в первом инпуте все норм работает а уже в 2 нехочет работать, странно(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором случае вы используете тот же термин что и в первом

```
var term = $('.select2-search__field').val();
```

Select2 с классом `.select2-search__field` у вас пять, а используется всегда первый селект и из него берется `term`

Просто получите термин из нужного селектбокса с помощью корректного css селектора.

Comment: Заманался с этим)) спасибо за помощь) точный ответ)